# How can I fix the 'string not a subtype of int' error when accessing my Flutter API for data display in a list?

Tags: flutter, api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XA5wP.png)

i do not know why is this telling me this ?

Exception has occurred.

-

_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

i am trying to access to my api  to show data in my list but it keep telling that
Exception has occurred.
_TypeError (type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index')

so how can I fixed ?

Comment: Can you include code-snippet instead as well, adding `data` as response(you can `print(data)`) will help us for better understanding.

Comment: The error message "string not a subtype of int" typically occurs when you're trying to treat a string value as an integer value or perform an operation that expects an integer but receives a string instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: thanks very much I already figured it out , the reason was that the data was null , because i was trying to access the json data in the wrong way through my api

Answer (score 1):

Without code to look at, I can't tell you specifically, but here's how you resolve such errors.

Convert string to int:

```
String stringValue = "42";
int intValue = int.parse(stringValue);
```

Convert int to string:

```
int intValue = 42;
String stringValue = "The value is: " + intValue.toString();
```